# When I pass string variables to controller in laravel via ajax, It doesn't show me proper data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

This is my Ajax Query

```
  function updateTask() {
    var task_id = document.getElementById('edit').getAttribute('edit_task_id');
    var newTask = document.getElementById('edit_task').value;
    var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    var close = document.getElementById('close');
    var editob = new XMLHttpRequest();
    editob.open('POST', '/{task_id}/{newTask}', true);
    editob.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf);
    editob.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    editob.send("task_id=" + task_id, "newTask=" + newTask);
    
    console.log(newTask);
    console.log(task_id);
  }
```

This is y Controller

```
    public function editTask($id, $newTask){
        //$x = $id->get('task_id');
         print_r($id);
         print_r($newTask);
         
    }
```

And this is the response I get, butI actually want the proper string value that I passed through ajax
[image: This is what i get as response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, your script shows proper data what you asking for

```
editob.open('POST', '/{task_id}/{newTask}', true);
```

here your URL looks something like this. because you sending a string instead of a value

```
http://your-domain.com/{task_id}/{newTask}
```

what you need to do is

```
editob.open('POST',  `/${task_id}/${newTask}`, true);
```

Comment: This works very well , thank You

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a raw string here

```
editob.open('POST', '/{task_id}/{newTask}', true);
```

that is why, it works in php not in js, for JS use

```
editob.open('POST', '/' + task_id + '/' + newTask, true);
```